# how does prolog loop through this code

Tags: loops, prolog

How does this code work? I wold have tough it worked for the first possible values of `C` and `X`, but somehow it loops.

```
path(A, B, [A, B], X) :-
    route(A, B, X).
path(A, B, PathAB, Length) :-
    route(A, C, X),
    path(C, B, PathCB, LengthCB),
    PathAB = [A | PathCB],
    Length is X + LengthCB.
```

there are `routes` defind as `route(bahirdar, mota, 32).`.

Comment: In this case, Prolog isn't "looping". Prolog attempts to determine if a query is "true". If it's true, it moves on to the next query (when using the comma (`,`) operator). If a query is "false", then Prolog "backtracks" to the prior query and tries to find another way to make it succeed (through different instantiation of the variables) and, if it can, it goes forward again. So in effect, it's bouncing back and forth trying to make the predicate succeed. :)

Comment: @lurker Can you make that an answer, that is sort of what i was looking for! But where is it being false? I see no where false there.

Comment: I will post something more explanatory later this evening when I have time (unless someone beats me to it. :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a simpler example, suppose you have the following facts:

```
foo(1).
foo(2).
```

Then you query:

```
| ?- foo(X).
```

Prolog will succeed with `X = 1` and prompt:

```
X = 1 ?
```

The `?` indicates that there was a choice point (it found additional options to explore for `foo`), and if you press `;` and Enter, it will *backtrack* and try to find another solution, which it does, and prompts:

```
X = 2 ?
```

Now if you press `;` and Enter it will fail and stop because it can't succeed any further.

Let's try something a little more elaborate with a conjunction. Use the facts:

```
foo(1).
foo(2).
foo(3).
```

And the rule:

```
odd(X) :- X /\ 1 =:= 1.   % X is odd if X bit-wise and with 1 is 1
```

And then do a query that says I want `X` to be `foo` **and** I want `X` to be `odd`:

```
| ?- foo(X), odd(X).
X = 1 ? ;
X = 3 ? ;
no
| ?-
```

Note that we only get the odd solutions. What happens in this query is as follows:

1. Prolog calls `foo(X)` and succeeds with `X = 1`.
2. Prolog calls `odd(1)` (since `X` is instantiated as 1) and succeeds
3. Prolog shows the result `X = 1`.
4. The user indicates a backtrack is desired (find more solutions)
5. Prolog backtracks to `odd(1)`, which has no variables to reinstantiate, so  Prolog backtracks further
6. Prolog backtracks to `foo(X)` and succeeds with `X = 2` and proceeds ahead again
7. Prolog calls `odd(2)` and fails. The failure causes Prolog to backtrack to the `foo` call
8. Prolog backtracks to `foo(X)` and succeeds with `X = 3` and proceeds ahead again
9. Prolog calls `odd(3)` and succeeds and displays the solution `X = 3`<
10. ...

Apply this now to your predicate:

```
path(A, B, [A, B], X) :-
    route(A, B, X).
path(A, B, PathAB, Length) :-
    route(A, C, X),
    path(C, B, PathCB, LengthCB),
    PathAB = [A | PathCB],
    Length is X + LengthCB.
```

If a query is made to `path`, Prolog first attempts to match the query to the head of the first clause `path(A, B, [A, B], X)`. A match to this head would mean that the 3rd argument would have to be a list consisting of exactly 2 elements. If there's a match, Prolog will call `route(A, B, X)`. If `route(A, B, X)` succeeds, Prolog will display the values of `A`, `B`, and `X` that resulted in the success. If the user prompts for more solutions, Prolog will backtrack which would either (a) call `route(A, B, X)` again if there was a choice point left in the prior call, or (b) backtrack further and attempt to match the original call to `path` to the second clause, `path(A, B, PathAB, Length)`. Similarly, if the original call to `route(A, B, X)` had failed, Prolog would backtrack to attempt to match the second clause.

If executing the second clause, you have the conjunction case like shown in the prior simplified example. Here, it's conjunctive sequence of four calls starting with `route(A, C, X)`. Prolog will attempt each of these calls in sequence and move to the next as long as the prior succeeds. When a failure is encountered, Prolog will backtrack to the prior call and, if there was a choice point, attempt a reinstantiation of arguments to make the prior call succeed again, etc.

Perhaps you can see how this is different than *looping*. In a typical imperative language, you might have a loop consisting of the following statements:

```
while (something) do
    A
    B
    C
end
```

Which would execute as `A B C A B C A B C ...` until the loop condition is met. In Prolog, you might have:

```
A,
B,
C,
```

Which may execute as: `A(succeeds) B(fails - backtrack) A(succeeds) B(fails - backtrack) A(succeeds) B(succeeds) C(fails - backtrack) B(succeeds) C(succeeds)` and then finally yield results.

If this were a *really* good answer, I'd include a bunch of diagrams to illustrate this. But I hope the description helps enough. :)